# Mule JDBC combine result set

Tags: mule

I have a JDBC connector as an inbound endpoint fetching the correct result set in my database.
I've noticed that each row is returned as a new message. 

**My question:** How do I combine all rows into one message? Is the aggregator the only option?

using Mule version 3.3.1 CE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:jersey="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey"
xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jdbc"
xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:mongo="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mongo"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jdbc http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jdbc/current/mule-jdbc.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey/current/mule-jersey.xsd "    version="CE-3.3.1">




<context:property-placeholder location="configuration.properties" />
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <spring:property name="driverClassName" value="mydriver"/>
        <spring:property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <spring:property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}"/>
        <spring:property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>

<jdbc:connector name="AS400" dataSource-ref="dataSource"
    validateConnections="true" 
    queryTimeout="-1" 
    pollingFrequency="5000"
    transactionPerMessage="false"
    doc:name="Database">
    <jdbc:query key="selectNums" value="select someColumns from someTable"/>

</jdbc:connector>


<flow name="databaseFlow" doc:name="databaseFlow" processingStrategy="synchronous">


    <jdbc:inbound-endpoint 

        queryKey="selectNums" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="AS400"
        doc:name="select-record" pollingFrequency="45000">
    </jdbc:inbound-endpoint>


    <logger message="msg to send:  #[map-payload:col1]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
    <logger message="phone number: #[map-payload:col2]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />


    <custom-transformer class="myTransformer" doc:name="Java"/>

</flow>
```

Comment: Provide your mule config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To receive a single message that contains all the rows, either:

1. Start a transaction in the JDBC inbound endpoint with `<jdbc:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>` and set `transactionPerMessage="false"` on the JDBC endpoint,

   or
2. Poll a JDBC outbound endpoint at the beginning of your flow:

   ```
   <poll frequency="${polling.frequency}">
       <jdbc:outbound-endpoint queryKey="..."
           exchange-pattern="request-response" queryTimeout="30000" />
   </poll>
   ```

In both cases you will get a single message with `List<Map<String, Object>>` payload.

Comment: As you can see from my flow I do set the 'transactionPerMessage="false"', but I get a CaseInsensitiveHashMap for each row and not a List.

Comment: Re-read my answer: you also need to start a transaction in the JDBC inbound endpoint for this setting to have any effect.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm missing something. When you say 'either' and 'In both cases' does each bullet work by itself as a solution or do both need to be added? Also, why is the polling needed if I'm already setting the polling frequency in my jdbc connector? Thanks.

Comment: Yes by 'either' I mean you can use either strategy to achieve your goal. And by 'in both cases' I meant that whether you follow the first or the second option, the said result will be reached. I'll replace the bullets with numbers to see if it makes it clearer for you. Also a poller is needed in the second case because it is an outbound endpoint not an inbound endpoint.

Comment: thank you for your response. I'm trying your first proposed solution. I set

Comment: I set the transactionPerMessage="false" in my global connector and then in my flow I have a jdbc:inbound that references that connector. The transactionPerMessage is set and I have the poller to start the transaction, but the result set is still coming on the payload one message at a time.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have the poller to start the transaction"?

Comment: I'm setting the pollingFrequency on the jdbc:inbound. Although it does say that this is the delay for two subsequent calls in which I'm not sure what triggers the process in the first place since I've able to receive and parse the messages.

Comment: Did you configure a transaction element in the JDBC inbound-endpoint to start a transaction? Without that you will not get a single message.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. When I have <jdbc:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/> to begin the transaction and transactionPerMessage="false" it works. Thank you so much for your help.